# Multiple Django subforms displayed with ajax in a main form but data not registered when subforms are submited (without error)

Tags: django, ajax, django-forms

EDIT #1

well maybe because it is not clear in my head
and your are right saying Django forms are not intented to be used with ajax that why I wonder if there is way way doing what I want using Django forms without losing power of Django forms validation

I will try to clear my demand

considering this UI below

1. When user reach this "patient page" = main form (image 1), he can select "Inclusion form = subform (INCL-001 for instance) in the menu

I want the corresponding form to be displayed without refresh the page ; that why I have used ajax to display the corresponding form

2. If the corresponding form does not exist, it is a CREATION and a blank "Inclusion form" is displayed : user can enter data and save
3. If the corresponding form already exist, it is a UPDATE and a prefilled "Inclusion form" is displayed : user can update data and save or delete the form

what would be an elegant way of doing that?

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

I have a main form (patient.html) and I want to display different subforms (inclusion.html for instance) with ajax in this form.
I manage to display a subform when user click on a button in the main form

But, data are not stored when submitted and it is quite normal as no view is linked to this subform
I have read about this in different post but I miss the concept how to...

I thinks it is a common task with web so probably Django as an easy way to do it?

thanks for advices

urls.py

```
app_name='ecrf'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('patient/<pk>', views.patient, name='patient'),
    path('sub_form', views.sub_form, name='sub_form'),

]
```

views.py

```
def patient(request,pk):
    patient = {"id":1,"num":'A-001',"dat":'Mon 11, novembre 2020',"arm":1,"doc":'Slater'}
    return render(request, 'ecrf/patient.html', {'patient':patient})

def sub_form(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        return JsonResponse(
            {
                'html_inclusion': render_to_string(
                    'ecrf/inclusion.html',
                    {
                        'form': InclusionForm,
                        'language': request.session.get('language')
                    },
                    request=request
                ),                                 
            },
            status=200
            )
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    ...
    
    $("#add").on("click",function (event) {
        var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/ecrf/sub_form',
            data: {
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken,
            },
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#sub_form").children().remove();
                obj = JSON.parse(data);
                $("#sub_form").append(obj.html_inclusion);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log('error');
            }
        });       

    });

    
    $("body")
        .on("click", '#inclusion', function (event) {
            console.log('inclusion click')
        })




});
```

Comment: Django forms are typically meant to be used without ajax. It's not exactly clear to me what you are trying to do here, and what is not working as expected. There are many things that could go wrong in a process such a this one. To debug, you should look at the actual html produced from the view and from the jquery callback, as well as the http requests sent, including headers and payload. You can use the web browser development tools to inspect these things.

Comment: Note: When you submit a html form, the standard process is to only submit data from one html form element. There's no such thing as a "sub form" in the html standard, and a form element should not have any form elements as descendants.

Comment: thanks for replying ; I add some screenshot to explain better what I need